# How to move the contents of a table in sql server to another with out using create

Tags: sql-server

```
I'm trying to move a table in sql server to another table without the use of create. Is there any way to accomplish this.
```

I'm trying to use the `select * from table`

Comment: "Move" and "Copy" mean very different things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SELECT . . INTO` :

```
SELECT s.* 
INTO <destination>
FROM <source> s;
```

This will create `<DESTINATION>` table with auto fill data.

Note : This will copy the table definition only includes (column/datatype).

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need the create table permission in the destination database to create this new table. Also, if the new table already exists an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @Pepelui360. . . This is the basic thing that OP should know.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple insert query

```
   insert into destination(columns)
    select *
    from source
    where<condition>;
```

> And delete existing record if you want

```
  delete from source
      where <condition>
  commit;
```

Answer (score -1):

The SELECT INTO statement creates a new table and inserts rows from the query into it.
Please refer [this](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-into/) for more information.

```
SELECT 
    select_list
INTO 
    destination
FROM 
    source
[WHERE condition]
```